# Entity Framework Core Navigation Properties and Joins, Correct Pattern

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to understand the best way to implement some database relationships in EF Core.

Specifically, it involves the navigation properties, where you make a collection in the parent and an object in the child.

Looking at the MS docs here

[Relationships, navigation properties, and foreign keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)

there is the typical use case presented of a parent child relationship

```
public class Course
{
  public int CourseID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int Credits { get; set; }
  public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
  public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
   public Department()
   {
     this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
   }  
   public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Budget { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Now this is fine for the above use case.

However, I am working on a specification system for process recipes. There are lots of machines, materials, areas, buildings and other things involved.

One of the tables in the database is "Unit", as in unit of measurement - that is kg, m, cm, etc.

This table is used as a lookup in many tables in the database, at least 20.

As such, if I've understood the recommended approach, I would end up with

```
pubic class Unit
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Recipes> Recipes{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Coll2> Coll2{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Coll3> Coll2{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Coll4> Coll2{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Coll5> Coll2{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Coll..n> Coll..n{ get; set; }
}
```

This applies not just for unit, but also for quite a few other generic lookup items, such as a warehouse. There are many entities that use a link to the warehouse.

What is the correct approach when using this kind of lookup?

I'm sorry if things aren't clear, hopefully they are.

Comment: The "rule" is simple. You're in the driver seat, totally. There's no best practice other than: create the navigation properties you need, not all that *can* be made. Usually you won't want to navigate from lookups to referring entities, so remove the collections.

Comment: Ok, thank you for such a fast reply. The issue that is then confusing for me is how to load the lookup data in the correct way. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you should edit your question and explain this aspect.

Comment: Well you won't understand, I didn't explain it :), but thank you. I've been working on moving a large application that is a Django backend (a world I am much more familiar with) to using .net core. I really like the concept of the code first EF approach, the identity system and also how you can separate concerns easily - especially compared to what Python has to offer with the various frameworks. The problem is there seem to be many ways to achieve the same thing, and it's confusing to know what is best. The documentation is very hard to understand, and the opposite of concise, imho.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong documentation (for EF6). The corresponding for EF Core is [Relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). It contains the definition of terms and a lot of examples, including [Single navigation property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property), although it is for *collection navigation property* at *one* side, but the same applies for *reference* navigation at *many* side.

Comment: In simple words, all these collection properties are not mandatory, you don't have to have them in *principal* (referenced) entity `Unit`.  Having `public Unit Unit { get; set; }` reference navigation property in *dependent* (referencing) entities would be enough to introduce the desired relationships and access/load the related data from these entities.